# Performance in Match formula in For Loop

Tags: excel, vba

The following code works but I am trying to find a more efficient way to do the same thing because it takes forever. I have about 30 chunks of code doing the same thing and altogether it takes 3-4 hours to run.

The beginning of the code is simple and not the problem. For column M, it matches on product id (RC[-12]) and Activity code (R4C2) in a different sheet (DeSL_CP_Table) and returns the baseline end date. Same for column N but returning the Completion date. The activity code in R4C2 is a code that is for licensed products only.

I then need to do the same thing for unlicensed product but can't use a autofill because I don't want to overwrite the licensed data above. Column AK tells me whether a product is licensed or unlicensed. Activity code in R5C2 is for unlicensed product. The if statement withing the for loop isn't terrible if run once, but I I do this for many other columns seeking other similar things in my report. Any help on a faster way to run this would be great.

```
Sheets("Summary").Select
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Licensed
Range("M7").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=INDEX(DeSL_CP_Table[BaseLineEnd],MATCH(RC[-12]&R4C2,DeSL_CP_Table[ProductID]&DeSL_CP_Table[ActivityCode],0))"
Range("N7").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=INDEX(DeSL_CP_Table[CompletionDate],MATCH(RC[-13]&R4C2,DeSL_CP_Table[ProductID]&DeSL_CP_Table[ActivityCode],0))"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("M7:n" & lastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault

On Error Resume Next
Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).ClearContents ' Delete #N/A
On Error GoTo 0

'Unlicensed
Dim strVal As String
Dim ranA As Range

For Each ranA In Range("AK2:AK" & lastRow) ' look through unlicensed
    strVal = ranA
    'MsgBox (strVal)
    If strVal = "Unlicensed" Then
        ranA.Offset(0, -24).FormulaArray = _
         "=INDEX(DeSL_CP_Table[BaseLineEnd],MATCH(RC[-12]&R5C2,DeSL_CP_Table[ProductID]&DeSL_CP_Table[ActivityCode],0))"
        ranA.Offset(0, -23).FormulaArray = _
         "=INDEX(DeSL_CP_Table[CompletionDate],MATCH(RC[-13]&R5C2,DeSL_CP_Table[ProductID]&DeSL_CP_Table[ActivityCode],0))"
    End If
 Next ranA
```

I tried arrays but it actually takes longer. This is the piece for just unlicensed.

```
Dim lastRow1 As Long
lastRow1 = Sheets("DeSL_CP").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Dim BaselineEnd As Variant, ActivityCode As Variant, ProductID As Variant
BaselineEnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DeSL_CP").Range("P2:P" & lastRow1).Value
ActivityCode = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DeSL_CP").Range("K2:K" & lastRow1).Value
ProductID = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DeSL_CP").Range("B2:B" & lastRow1).Value

Dim resultArray() As String
ReDim resultArray(7 To lastRow)
Dim i As Long, j As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
For i = 7 To lastRow
    resultArray(i) = ""
    For j = 1 To UBound(ActivityCode)
    If .Range("AK" & i).Value = "Unlicensed" Then
        If ActivityCode(j, 1) = "AA0001" Then
            If .Range("A" & i).Value = ProductID(j, 1) Then
                    resultArray(i) = BaselineEnd
                    Exit For
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Next j
Next i

.Range("M7").Resize(lastRow - 3 + 1, 1).Value = resultArray
End With
```

Comment: You need to turn off calculation. Every time you add your formula array in your loop the worksheet recalculates. `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual`

Comment: I would also consider reading and writing your values to an array, then once you have finished looping write the array to the worksheet. Writing to an array is _significantly faster_ than writing to the worksheet. If you do this, then the above wouldn't really be necessary.

Comment: on your first comment: If I am understanding it correctly, you are suggesting I add Application.Calculation = xlManual at the beginning of my code and then switch it back to automatic at the end. If that is the case, I tried it and it isn't any faster. Is that it or should I try something else.

Comment: On the second, I tried an array and am getting an error... I haven't done a lot of array coding so I am probably missing something. Will edit the post and add what I have done...

Comment: Wow your 3-4 hours must be different than my 3-4 hours if you already tested it ;P

Comment: ha! I tested on just that piece of code... which takes a few minutes and still did... it is doing that code over and over again that takes the 3-4 hours

Comment: `ActivityCode` will have `lastrow1`-1 elements as it starts at K2 so I imagine the error occurs on the last iteration of your `j` loop.

Comment: Thanks SJR, that fixed it. So good news is the array code works. Bad news is it actually takes longer than the other method. Any ideas?

Comment: @spaindc you seems to have missed the point of using arrays.  You still have two range references inside the loops `.Range("AK" & i).Value` and `.Range("A" & i)` .  Converting those ranges to arrays also, would speed things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out how to correct the arrays - see post "VBA Array help - no errors but does not return correct data" - has three different ways to go about this issue with the time each took to run. This one takes under 10 seconds, vs 3-5 minutes for the other two.

```
Option Base 1

Sub FillInConcept()

Sheets("Summary").Select
Dim lastRow As Long, lastRow1 As Long
lastRow = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow1 = Sheets("DeSL_CP").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lastRow1 = lastRow1 - 1


Dim BaselineEnd As Variant, ActivityCode As Variant, ProductIDDeSL As Variant, 
Licensed As Variant, ProductIDSumm As Variant
BaselineEnd = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DeSL_CP").Range("P2:P" & lastRow1).Value
ActivityCode = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DeSL_CP").Range("K2:K" & lastRow1).Value
ProductIDDeSL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DeSL_CP").Range("B2:B" & lastRow1).Value
Licensed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("AK7:AK" & lastRow).Value
ProductIDSumm = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("A7:A" & lastRow).Value

Dim resultArray() As Date
ReDim resultArray(lastRow - 7 + 1, 1)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
For i = 1 To UBound(ProductIDSumm)
For j = 1 To UBound(ProductIDDeSL)
'If Not Sheets("DeSL_CP").Rows(j).Hidden Then
If ProductIDSumm(i, 1) = ProductIDDeSL(j, 1) Then
    If Licensed(i, 1) = "Unlicensed" Then
        If ActivityCode(j, 1) = "AA0001" Then
        resultArray(i, 1) = BaselineEnd(j, 1)
        Exit For
        End If
    Else
        If ActivityCode(j, 1) = "A0003" Then
        resultArray(i, 1) = BaselineEnd(j, 1)
        Exit For
        End If
    End If
End If
'End If
Next j
Next i

WorksheetFunction.Transpose (resultArray)
Range("M7").Resize(UBound(resultArray), 1).Value = resultArray
End With
End Sub
```